# How to increase bufsize in latex when using rmarkdown through texmf.cnf

Tags: latex, r-markdown, pandoc

I'm not able to increase bufsize in texmf.cnf. I'm working with Windows, and I've followed directions at other places.

Can someone direct me to this "texmf.cnf" file so that I can edit the bufsize? I've searched my directory and I see no such file.

Here is my error message:

> Unable to read an entire line--bufsize=200000
>   Please increase buf_size in texmf.cnf

Thanks for your help.

Comment: There is an answer on https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43430/how-to-increase-bufsize-for-lualatex-or-pdflatex

Answer (score -1):

Please use `latex -buf-size=999999`